# Why does my std::ref not work as expected?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, higher-order-functions, pass-by-value

`std::ref` gives you a `lvalue-reference` to something. This reference is wrapped into an object that you can then pass around either by reference or by value.

The **expected behavior** of the code below  is that it prints `i is 2`, but it prints `i is 1`. **Why is that?**

**Why do I have this expectation?** Because I am passing `tmp` via `std::ref` to `wrapper`. In wrapper the reference is then captured by value. I would have assumed that, since I am using `std::ref` this value is now still a reference to `tmp`. I am changing `tmp` and would expect that `f` reflects that change.

[Play with the code here.](https://godbolt.org/z/XrxDBX)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename F>
auto wrapper(int i, F func) {
    return [=]() { return func(i); };
}

void f(int i) {
    std::cout << "i is " << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int tmp = 1;
    auto func = wrapper(std::ref(tmp), f);
    tmp = 2;
    func();
}
```

Comment: "*`std::ref` gives you a `lvalue-reference` to something*" - **no**. It gives you `std::reference_wrapper` to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because your `wrapper` function takes an `int` as argument.

`std::ref` returns a `std::reference_wrapper`.
When you pass it to a function that wants an `int`
 you will get an implicit conversion and you arre no longer working with a reference.

If you change your function signature to use a `std::reference_wrapper` it will give the intended result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename F>
auto wrapper(std::reference_wrapper<int> i, F func) {
    return [=]() { return func(i); };
}

void f(int i) {
    std::cout << "i is " << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int tmp = 1;
    auto func = wrapper(std::ref(tmp), f);
    tmp = 2;
    func();
}
```

Comment: Now this makes a lot of sense! I was not aware of the implicit conversion of the `reference_wrapper<int>` to `int`. But yea, sound logical. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change function signatures to accept references:

1. `auto wrapper(int& i, F func) {...}`
2. `void f(int& i) {...}`

and also make lambda capture by reference `return [&]() { return func(i); };`. Then you don't need `std::ref`.

Full code would be like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename F>
auto wrapper(int& i, F func) {
    return [&]() { return func(i); };
}

void f(int& i) {
    std::cout << "i is " << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int tmp = 1;
    auto func = wrapper(tmp, f);
    tmp = 2;
    func();
}
```

Now the above code would print:

```
i is 2
```

If you would still like to use `std::ref`, then your template function should have the following signature:

```cpp
template<typename F>
auto wrapper(std::reference_wrapper<int> i, F func) {...}
```

Comment: Okay... But why does `std::ref` not do that for me? I thought one of its points is to have a reference to something, even when I am passing by value

Comment: @User12547645 because your functions are not accepting references or `std::reference_wrapper<int>`. They accept copies.